# Ebean query seems to stop execution

Tags: java, orm, ebean

I am trying to do a fairly simple Ebean query:

```
 Long articleId = Long.parseLong(dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("id"));
 System.out.println("Article ID");
 System.out.println(articleId);
 Article article = DB.find(Article.class).where().eq("id", articleId).findOne();
 System.out.println("Article");
 System.out.println(article);
```

Article ID prints to the console, articleId prints to the console

However everything after the query does not. Absolutely no logging at all.

I've tried to enable a logback.xml on all of the queries, I'm not seeing any errors.

What could be going on here? Clearly there's some problem going on that is not being made available for me to see - how do I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something like this works:

```
 Article article = DB.find(Article.class)
.select("id, title, body").where().eq("id", articleId)
.findOne();

System.out.println("Article");
System.out.println(article);
```

Not entirely sure what the difference is, as the Ebeans documentation is a little sparse, but this works for me

Comment: It should also work the first way

Comment: Use **select()** to select only certain fields and if not used it will return all fields, so the first method was supposed to work as well, you can also try like this  **DB.find(Article.class,articleId)**

Answer (score 0):

> see your log , **io.ebean.SQL - txn[txnNum] -> your query** , **io.ebean.SUM - txn[txNum] -> find bean or not**

if find -> **row[1]** :

```
io.ebean.SUM - txn[txNum] FindBean type[beanType] origin[DrFzdL.A.A] exeMicros[num] rows[1] bind[beanId, ]
```

if not find -> **row[0]** :

```
io.ebean.SUM - txn[txNum] FindBean type[beanType] origin[DrFzdL.A.A] exeMicros[num] rows[0] bind[beanId, ]
```